# How do I properly edit/remove elements from an Ansible dict/variable?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

So I have a variable, let's call it 'value', and as you know it is composed of the following:

```
 "delta": "0:00:00.021861",
    "end": "2019-01-17 10:16:50.303568",
    "failed": false,
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2019-01-17 10:16:50.281707",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": A, B, C, D, E, F, G"
    "stdout_lines": A, B, C, D, E, F, G"
```

Now, I needed to edit that variable, so I ran a with_items loop as follows:

```
- set_fact:
    new_value: "{{ new_value | default([]) | union([item])}}"
    when: ...if letter is a vowel...
  with_items: "{{ value.stdout_lines }}"
```

Then I do:

```
- set_fact:
    value: new_value
```

The problem is, now it is no longer the same type of object it used to be, it's just a plain old list because I looped through '.stdout_lines'

Is there a way to fix this so that the 'new_value' also has all the previous info, such as: "delta", "end", "stderr", etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit existing fact, but you can set a new fact modified as you want.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        value:
           delta: '0:00:00.021861'
           end: '2019-01-17 10:16:50.303568'
           start: '2019-01-17 10:16:50.281707'
           stdout_lines: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

    - set_fact:
        new_value: "{{ value.stdout_lines | select('match', '[AE]') | list }}"

    - set_fact:
        value: "{{ value | combine({'stdout_lines': new_value}) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ value }}"
```

Here we use `combine` filter to overwrite part of original dictionary with new value.

Comment: Worked marvelously!